# Java: Access a Jframe Label from a static class

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans, static

I've been having a little trouble, first time OOP programming, updating a JFrame Label from another class.

I can access the class and static variables in the class, I've even tried accessing static methods/functions, but still can't access the JFrame Label from inside the method.

I currently have 2 classes GUI.java and Credit.java, GUI.java has the JFrame.

GUI.Java has a label lblLCD and is coded:

```
public class GUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    public static String LCDString = "":
    public GUI() {
        initComponents();
    }

    public static void RefreshLCD() {
        lblLCD.setText(LCDString);
    }
}
```

And Credit.java has no JFrame and is coded:

```
public class Credit {
    public static void Reset() {
        GUI.RefreshLCD();
    }
}
```

Any ideas on how i can get around this?

Comment: What errors/exceptions is it giving? Please post it.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, that was the reason :P : "non-static variable lblLCD cannot be referenced from a static context"

Comment: `static` is not your friend and you should make pains to avoid it.  In your case, you should be dealing with the instance of the frame to which you want to make the changes

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I've now noticed how bad they are and how to get around using them :D Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access non-static variables from a static method. You might want to look into more information about the static keyword. Also, using a lot of static methods can be a sign of poor design. It feels like in your example you should be using less static methods.

That being said, you are going to require a reference to the instance of your JFrame (GUI), to be able to call non-static methods.

I've created some sample code that I hope will help you:

GUI.java

```
public class GUI extends JFrame{
    // Note: this should probably not be a static variable
    // You can use a private, non-static variable and create a getter/setter method for it
    public static String LCDString = ""; 

    public GUI(){
        initComponents();
    }

    // Note: methods in Java start with a lowercase letter
    public void refreshLCD(){
        lblLCD.setText(LCDString);
    }
}
```

Credit.java

```
public class Credit {
    // Keep a reference to your jframe, so you can call non-static public methods on it
    private GUI gui;

    // Pass a GUI object to your Credit object
    public Credit(GUI gui){
        this.gui = gui;
    }

    // This should also probably not be a static method.
    // Note: methods in Java should start with a lowercase letter
    public void reset(){
        gui.refreshLCD();
    }
}
```

Main method

```
//Your main method
public static void main(String[] args){
    // Create a variable for your new GUI object
    GUI gui = new GUI();
    // Pass our new GUI variable to the Credit object we're creating
    Credit credit = new Credit(gui);

    // Lets set some text
    GUI.LCDString = "Hello World";
    // If LCDString was not static it would be something like this:
    // gui.setLCDString("Hello World");

    // Now we have a credit instance and can call the reset() method on this object
    credit.reset();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what i wanted.
I didn't realise that static variables were bad, I read that they were needed to be accessed by other classes. I didn't think about creating the external classes and keeping references to them :D
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is because, from your question I can make out, that your variable `lblLCD` is non-static. And non-static variables cannot be reffered from within a `static` method.

To refer to that non-static variable, you need to first instantiate the class GUI and then refer to it using the object.

```
public static void RefreshLCD() {
    GUI gui = new GUI();
    gui.lblLCD.setText(LCDString);
}
```

#### OR

make the variable `lblLCD` static.

## Suggestion:

Do not use `static` for this purpose. Make the method `RefreshLCD()`, method `Reset()` and the variable `LCDString` non-static.

And from within your `Reset()` method, instatiate the `class GUI` and call the `RefreshLCD()` method.

```
public class GUI extends JFrame {

    public String LCDString = "";

    public GUI() {

        initComponents();
    }
    public void RefreshLCD() {

        lblLCD.setText(LCDString);
    }   
}  


public class Credit {

    public void Reset() {

        new GUI().RefreshLCD();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your first example is going to cause a new frame to be created every time the method is called, which I doubt is really the intention of the OP and `static` is generally a bad idea

Comment: He has made a bad desing. So he must expect such answers.

Comment: Or you could suggest a better/more professional design which would solve their problem, rather then creating new ones